# Traversing subgroups and group layers with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layertree

I am trying to find the name of subgroups using PyQGIS. I have been trying to use [Playing with subgroups](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/25/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-2/)

I am however unable to traverse and get the names of the subgroup. I have tried the code on this article.

```
for child in root.children():
  if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    print "- group: " + child.name()
    if child.name() == "test": #to check subgroups within test group
        for child in root.children(): #which I think i am making a mistake here because the root is supposed to contain all nodes
```

Comment: Hi @kartoza-geek, can you elaborate on the output of the above script and at which stage it fails?

Comment: The script runs well but does not give expected results. If I have a group layer called test and subgroups called test 1 and test 2 they are not printed

Comment: Try `for subChild in child.children():` and then `print subChild.name()`, since you want to start reading children from your main group (not from root anymore).

Comment: for some reason it does not work. It throws an error QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'name.

Comment: the instance has to be subchild for it to work.

Comment: Perhaps you could mention which version of QGIS you are using please? I can confirm  (using QGIS 2.8.2) that @gcarrillo 's suggestion works.

Comment: it does work. I can confirm as well. for subChild in child.children(): if if isinstance(subchild, QgsLayerTreeGroup): and then print the subChild.name()

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so that we can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to start reading children from your main group (not from root anymore), try this (pay attention to the last 3 lines):

```
for child in root.children():
  if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    print "- group: " + child.name()
    if child.name() == "test": #to check subgroups within test group
        for subChild in child.children():
            if isinstance(subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                subChild.name()
```

Comment: yes, it worked. That's the code I ended up using. thanks for the help