# How to find a layer by name in the QGIS layer panel?

Tags: qgis, layers, panel

I have a large QGIS project organized with several groups in the QGIS layer panel. It happend to me a couple of times that, when the computer is operating with low resources (low free memory-high CPU usage), the exact control of the mouse is lost for some seconds and I by mistake dragged and dropped a layer into another group.
Then to find where it went manually could take a long time.

Is there a way to look for layers by name in the Layers Panel?

Comment: The answer posted in the following post allows you to see which group a particular layer is in via the **Python Console**: [pyqgis traversing subgroups and group layers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162080/pyqgis-traversing-subgroups-and-group-layers)

Comment: Thanks.. I thought there was an easier way to perform this simple task.

Comment: Most welcome! I thought so to (before I deleted my answer!). Perhaps there is but not something I know of :)

Comment: Yes, there is a very easy way, that doesn't require PyQGIS. In the lower left seach box (with `Type to locate (Ctrl+k)` just write `l layername` (letter l followed by the layer name). You just need to write the very first letters and you will see the available layers and you can jump to the layer. Really cool feature.

Comment: @PolyGeo I think this question is different from the duplicated one. This one is related to QGIS GUI. The other is related to PyQGIS programming.

Comment: @jgrocha You have a rep of 3,000+ so if you think this or any closed question should be re-opened all you need to do is to vote for that.  Even if you had less reputation you would be able to edit this question and make it explicitly exclude a PyQGIS solution. If the question were in that state, and I saw it, then I too would vote to re-open it.