# How to get layers in x number of subgroups?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layers

I have a project which has dozens of groups and subgroups. E.g.:

```
Main_Group > Sub_Group_1 > Sub_Group_1A > Layer_1A
                                        > Layer_2A
```

How can I access those layers which are contained within `Sub_Group_1A`?

I currently have this:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
  if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
    if child.name() == "Main_Group":
        for subChild in child.children():
            if isinstance(subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                if subChild.name() == 'Sub_Group_1':
                    # What next?
```

---

I have read through the following sources and can get layers in `Sub_Group_1` but not in `Sub_Group_1A`:

- http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/
- [pyqgis traversing subgroups and group layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162080/pyqgis-traversing-subgroups-and-group-layers)

Comment: Would you like to access all layers in the tree or would you like to access specifically those of the Sub_Group_1A?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Apologies, I should edit the question to make this clear. Specifically layers within `Sub_Group_1A`. If you can post an answer showing a more _cleaner_ piece of code than what I posted, I will happily accept it :)

Comment: Just asked because the other option I mentioned in the comment is also interesting, but it's a different one.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Is that by any chance related to this post: [PyQGIS: How to get the list of valid layers in TOC?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150611/pyqgis-how-to-get-the-list-of-valid-layers-in-toc?rq=1)?

Comment: Exactly! I didnt't remember that answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a handy option in the `QgsLayerTreeGroup` class that you can use: `findGroup`. It traverses the whole tree. So, in your case, this would be enough:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
subGroup1A = root.findGroup('Sub_Group_1A')
for child in subGroup1A.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
        child.layerName()
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff! Many thanks =). I noticed this was _briefly_ mentioned in the [first source referenced](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/), guess I overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

Eugh, I guess one method is to:

1. Search the children of `Main_group`, then
2. Search the children of `Sub_Group_1` and then
3. Search the children of `Sub_Group_1A`.

Basically repeating the loops, I'm hoping there is a much nicer and efficient way of accessing those layers but for now, here's the code I used:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
        if child.name() == "Main_Group":
            for subChild in child.children():
                if isinstance(subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                    if subChild.name() == 'Sub_Group_1':
                        if isinstance(subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                            for sub_subChild in subChild.children():
                                if isinstance(sub_subChild, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
                                    if sub_subChild.name() == 'Sub_Group_1A':
                                        for layers in sub_subChild.children():
                                            print layers.layerName()
```

Answer (score 0):

For x number of subgroups you can use that script:

```
def getLayersOfGroup(group):
    """That function find all layers under given group"""
    for child in group.children():
        if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeLayer):
            print(child.layer().name()
        elif isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):
            getLayersOfGroup(child)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup("GROUP NAME")
if group:
    getLayersOfGroup(group)
```